# Format reference to items in nested list with cleveref

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, cleveref

I'm using the [cleveref package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) to format references in my documents. However I am having difficulties implementing different formats for labels referring to enumerate-lists, in particular nested list.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\creflabelformat{enumi}{#1(#2)#3}
\creflabelformat{enumii}{#1(#2)#3}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
  \item\label{fi} The first item
  \item the second item
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item the first sub-item
    \item\label{ssi} the second sub-item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

This is a fancy reference to the first item: \labelcref{fi}.

The second sub-item can be referred to as \labelcref{ssi}.

\end{document}
```

Ideally, I would like the first reference to be formatted as (i), and the second as (ii-b).

The actual output is the following:
[image]

As we can see, both labels look different, i() instead of (i); and iib instead of (b) [I don't how to use `creflabelformat to get (ii-b), so I went for (b) but even this doesn't work.]

I know there are a few questions, some recent, asking about formatting references to list items, but they didn't really help me.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `label`, `ref` keys from the `enumitem` package to control the format for the labels and the references (I added some settings for the third and fourth nesting levels just as an illustration):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\roman*),ref=(\roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\alph*),ref=(\roman{enumi}-\alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=(\Alph*),ref=(\roman{enumi}-\alph{enumii}-\Alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label=(\arabic*),ref=(\roman{enumi}-\alph{enumii}-\Alph{enumiii}-\arabic*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item\label{fi} The first item
  \item the second item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item the first sub-item
    \item\label{ssi} the second sub-item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item\label{fssi} the first subsub-item
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item the first subsubsub-item
          \item\label{ssssi} the second subsubsub-item
        \end{enumerate}
      \item the second subsub-item
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

This is a fancy reference to the first item: \cref{fi}.

The second sub-item can be referred to as \cref{ssi}.

The second subsub-item can be referred to as \cref{fssi}.

The second subsubsub-item can be referred to as \cref{ssssi}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The enumitem package seems to be very useful.